# PHP array_merge() function can not keep the numeric keys

Tags: php

Values in the input array with numeric keys will be renumbered with incrementing keys starting from zero in the result array.
Above is the PHP manual said,I want to keep the original numeric key,how to do it?

```
$arr_from_color_group = Model_Edit_Colorgroup::find('all', array('select' => array('display_name')));$temp = array();
     foreach ($arr_from_color_group as $item){
        $oldtemp = $temp;
         $temp = array($item->id => $item->display_name);
         $temp = array_merge($oldtemp,$temp);
     }
    $form->add(
            'item_color_group_id', 'a forgien key',
            array('options' => $temp, 'type' => 'select', 'value' => 'true')
    )->add_rule('required');
```

Comment: and what have you tried so far? SO is not a code writing service

Comment: I want to get an array of 'display_name' column and which the key is the id of display_name.so I can use this array to a select box without resulting a 'foreign key' error when I insert the form to DB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `array_merge()`, you can merge the arrays using the `+` operator to keep original keys:

```
$new_arr = $arr1 + $arr2;
```

[**See demo**](http://codepad.org/Tv9mEGpE)